# how to change background color of window?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to change background color of window to gray instead of the default white. I cannot do it at the moment.

Last attempt was the following in styles.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#EEEEEE</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I added this:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">#EEEEEE</item>
```

But this error is shown at build time:

Color types not allowed (at 'android:windowBackground' with value '#EEEEEE').

Activity has these attributes:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

Any help, please?

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Resources/values/colors.xml define the color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="window_background_color">#EEEEEE</color>
</resources>
```

and in styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background_color</item>
```